# NSFetchedResultsController and transient property for sections

Tags: iphone, core-data

In data model I have transient property `uppercaseFirstLetterOfName` which will return first letter of persistent property. I specify this property in

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortByWordDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                    initWithKey:@"subject" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortArray = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:sortByWordDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

NSFetchedResultsController* controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                    sectionNameKeyPath:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName" 
                    cacheName:@"Root"];
```

When I change the persistent object taken from fetchedresultscontroller so the section should be deleted, only `controller:didChangeObject` fires. But since the section is gone(in fact) I would expect `controller:didChangeSection` also be fired. Should I do something extra when modifying persistent object in order to make `controller:didChangeSection` invoked?

UPD:

This is transient property getter in model subclass

```
- (NSString *)uppercaseFirstLetterOfName 
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName"];
    NSString *aString = [[self valueForKey:@"subject"] uppercaseString];
    NSString *stringToReturn = [aString substringWithRange:
             [aString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName"];

    return stringToReturn;
}
```

Here I get the object and pass to view controller to modify

```
...
detailViewController.unit = (ModelClass*)[fetchedResultsController 
                                    objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
...
```

and finally data modification

```
unit.subject = someTextField.text;
...
[unit.managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

I don't have anything other special for transient object, so I don't modify it directly.

Comment: `detailViewController.unit = (ModelClass*)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` does not require nor want a cast since NSFRC, like most things in Objective-C, returns an `id`.  `detailViewController.unit = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` is correct.

Comment: Why not just do `NSString *stringToReturn = [[self.subject substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WIthout seeing the code surrounding the update of that transient property I would have to guess that you are having a KVO issue.  Can you post the code?

### Update

Do you have a custom setter for subject?  If not, do you have a dependent key set up for `uppercaseFirstLetterOfName`?  If not, then that is your issue.  Changing one value will not trigger the other value to change.  This is a KVO situation.

NSFetchedResultsController is observing the `uppercaseFirstLetterOfName` specifically and waiting for it to change.  It is not just watching the object to change.  Therefore when you change the subject you need to "flag" `uppercaseFirstLetterOfName` as touched as well.  The easiest way to do this is to add the following method to your `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingUppercaseFirstLetterOfName
{
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"Subject"];
}
```

This will tell KVO that whenever the `subject` property has changed that it should also fire a change notification for `UppercaseFirstLetterOfName`.

Comment: That may be the case, since I don't have neither one you mentioned. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Should `@"Subject"` be all lowercase, i.e., `@"subject"`?