# Group tableView by first character of name

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, magicalrecord

I try to group my `UITableView` by the first character of the name of the customer. I use MagicalRecords as a helper, because I get my data from a database.
What I have looks like this:

```
self.dataSource.resultsController = [Customer fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"lastName,firstName" ascending:YES delegate:self.dataSource];
```

I want to replace the `fetchAllGroupedBy:nil` to somewhat like `fetchAllGroupedBy:@"lastName.firstChararcter"`

I already tried `fetchAllGroupedBy:@"[lastname substringWithRange:[NSMakeRange(0, 1)]` but that does not work.

My question now is, is this even possible and if so, how?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a transient property "firstCharacter" to a Customer entity and group by it. 
See - [this so question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473714/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-transient-property-for-sections)